# Website redesign, web host change => lost rankings

Tags: seo, ranking, migration, redesign

I've recently revamped one of my websites (all the pages have changed). I've lost 20 ranks in Google.

This is what I have done:

1. Website revamp.
2. Changed host to a faster host, it's also nearer to my targetted audience.
3. Maintained most of the previous websites' URLs. I've placed 301s to the root on links that don't exist anymore as well.
4. I forgot to reindex my page / submit my sitemap to Google till this morning. (I'm wondering if this has anything to do with my lost in ranks.)

Comment: Note that you should not `301`-redirect to the homepage if a page no longer exists (unless its content is now part of the homepage). `404` (or `410`) should be used instead.

Comment: It sounds like you made three changes simultaneously:  1.  Moved hosting  2. Changed the look and feel of the site 3. Changed URLs.     When you changed URLs did you change domain name, or just different URL paths?

Comment: Hello Stephen, I've found the cause of the problems, and it's my site not retaining the same URL structure as it had previously. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue from the website revamp itself.

Its most probably to do with the 301 redirects.

Google once stated

> a small amount of PageRank is lost through a 301 redirect, which is
>   the same as through a link.

SEO Moz carried out some tests on this matter and seen a drop in traffic up to 15% for the keywords that were relevant.

Comment: A 15% loss of traffic is understandable... But I've actually dropped from the first page to the 5th ... Could the 301 redirects be reason enough for this dramatic drop? Thanks :)

Comment: If the keywords relate to the pages that are being 301 redirected I think it could be an indicator yes..

Comment: Right now the only page being 301-ed is the contact us page...

Comment: Maybe next time state that its only one page you have redirected then, you said, "301's" ... So please ignore my answer.

Comment: @CodeFluffer by the way no rank is lost during 301s - http://searchengineland.com/google-no-pagerank-dilution-using-301-302-30x-redirects-anymore-254608

Comment: I found that this issue was compounded with not retaining the same URL structure as before. Changing this seems to have fixed it. Thanks everyone!